# Window Script Host Permission denied

Tags: vbscript, windows-7

Running this very simple VBS script on a Win7 Professional 64 bit and getting a Permission 
denied (800A0046) error message. 
Is there a way to change the OS permissions to allow for that?

```
Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\Desktop\Source\1.txt", "C:\Users\Desktop\Destination"
FSO.Close
```

Comment: Is that the real path? `C:\Users\Desktop\..` or you forgot to put username there?

Comment: 1. You should end _the destination folder name_ with a backslash: `"C:\Users\Desktop\Destination\"`. 2. `FSO.Close`: `Close` is not valid metod for a `FileSystemObject` object

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission denied on CopyFile in VBS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071679/permission-denied-on-copyfile-in-vbs)

Comment: Thanks a bunch JoseFZ, all working now.