# Faster method to copy file

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to copy file using following script.

```
Option Explicit

Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO
Dim desfolder
Dim oShell
dim s

desfolder = "D:\Databases"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Recurse objFSO.GetFolder("D:\Databases\Images")

Sub Recurse(objFolder)
    Dim objFile, objSubFolder

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "tif" Then
            s = Right(objFile.Name, 10)
            S = Left(s, 1)
            If Left(s, 1) = "C" Then
                Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                oShell.Run "xcopy.exe " & objFile & " " & desfolder & " /R /Y", _
                    0, True
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Recurse objSubFolder
    Next
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is checking files in folders and subfolders. If file is tif then checking weather it contains required letter "C" at specific position. and using `xcopy` to copy the file.

It works fine but is very slow.
Is there any faster method to do this?

**Edit:** What I want exactly is to find `c*.tif` in a folder and its subfolders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `xcopy` then. Doing it your way spawns a new process each time you copy a file. Just use the file object's [`Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6973t06a.aspx) method and be done with it.

```vb
Sub Recurse(objFolder)
    Dim objFile, objSubFolder

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "tif" Then
            If LCase(Left(objFile.Name, 1) = "c" Then
                objFile.Copy desfolder & "\"
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Recurse objSubFolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that your destination path requires a trailing backslash because it's a folder (you'd get a ["permission denied" error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16088761/1630171) without it). Otherwise you need to specify the destination path including the filename, e.g. like this:

```vb
objFile.Copy objFSO.BuildPath(desfolder, objFile.Name)
```