# Move folder across network using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, permissions, ms-access-2013, filesystemobject

I am trying to figure out how to properly move folders on a Network Share using VBA code from an MS Access Form.

Currently I am trying to use the FileSystemObject.MoveFolder method but keep running into a "Permissions Denied" error.

I have referenced this SO question and none of the top suggestions worked.
[Permission denied on CopyFile in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071679/permission-denied-on-copyfile-in-vbs)

I have verified that the SourcePath and the DestinationPath both are valid by using this function to MoveFolders on my local machine. I have also verified that both Folders have the appropriate network permissions. See Below

[image: Source Folder] [image: Destination Folder]

So my question is, is there a way to provide credentials with the FileSystemObject? or should I be using a different function entirely?

**EDIT:**

I have verified that I can move the folders manually. I have tried the function with and without files in the source folder.

I also have tried hardcoding the source and destination paths into the `FSO.MoveFolder` Command

```
Private Sub Check6_AfterUpdate()

    On Error GoTo Err_DormantHandler
    Dim response As String
    Dim client As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim fromPath As String
    Dim toPath As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    client = Me.CustomerName.Value
    fromPath = "P:\__Active_Clients\" & client
    toPath = "R:\Dormant_Clients\"

    If Me.Check6.Value = True Then
        response = MsgBox("Would you like to automatically move the " & client & " folder to the dormant folder?", vbYesNo)

        If response = vbYes Then
            If FSO.FolderExists(fromPath) = False Then
                MsgBox fromPath & " doesn't exist."
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If FSO.FolderExists(toPath) = False Then
                MsgBox toPath & " doesn't exist."
                Exit Sub
            End If

            FSO.MoveFolder source:=fromPath, destination:=toPath
            MsgBox "The customer folder has been moved to " & vbNewLine & toPath, vbOKOnly
        End If

        If response = vbNo Then
            MsgBox "The customer folder will NOT be moved to dormant"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If


Exit_DormantHandler:
    Exit Sub

Err_DormantHandler:
    MsgBox "Error# " & Err & vbNewLine & "Description: " & Error$
    Resume Exit_DormantHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you perform the exact same move manually?

Comment: Yes i can. I have no problem moving it manually

Comment: Maybe try `FSO.MoveFolder source:=fromPath, destination:=toPath & client`

Comment: I believe that i tried that before, but I just checked again to make sure. No luck. Same error

Comment: what is the full text in your client variable?

Comment: @geeFlo its just a basic string. something like "Bobs machine shop"

Comment: and you've tried @TimWilliams suggestion of the `& client` but you added that to the actual `fso.MoveFolder` command and not to your `topath` declaration (because your `if fso.folderexists` would kick you out of the sub)

Comment: @geeFlo could you please better explain what you are trying to point out? i'm a bit confused

Comment: I was just making sure that you tried adding `client` to the actual movefolder command `FSO.MoveFolder source:=fromPath, destination:=toPath & client` and not in the `topath` declaration.  But I see that you tried hardcoding it in there, so that's not issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try with `xcopy` from windows :

```
Sub Test()
  XCopy "C:\source", "C:\destination\", elevated:=False
End Sub

Public Sub XCopy(source As String, destination As String, Optional elevated = False)
  Static shell As Object
  If shell Is Nothing Then Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

  Dim vArguments, vOperation
  vArguments = "/E /Y """ & source & """ """ & destination & """"
  vOperation = IIf(elevated, "runas", "")

  shell.ShellExecute "xcopy.exe", vArguments, "", vOperation, 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree and second this approach.  It has (at least) two advantages 1)  The Command (DOS) prompt gives better feedback (IMHO) and 2) Shelling will not block the VBA code.

Comment: This is a valid alternative. Thank you for providing the solution

Answer (score 0):

You could try the batch file route, do you get permission errors with this?   You'll need the scripting reference, but it looks like you already have that.

Note the `wait` is important here, without the pause this will not work.  Also note the trailing slash only in the newDir, not the orig

```
Sub Main()
    Dim origDir As String: origDir = "C:\Users\thomas.preston\Original"
    Dim newDir As String: newDir = "C:\Users\thomas.preston\Destination\"
    Dim batDir As String: batDir = "C:\Users\thomas.preston\Desktop"
    Dim contents As String

    If Not DirectoryExists(origDir) Then
        MsgBox "Directory deos not exist: " & vbCrLf & origDir
        Exit Sub
    Else
        contents = "move """ & origDir & """ """ & newDir & """"
        MakeBat batDir & "\" & "ILikeToLoveItMoveIt.bat", contents
        FireBat batDir & "\" & "ILikeToLoveItMoveIt.bat"
        Application.Wait DateAdd("S", 2, Now)
    End If

    If DirectoryExists(newDir & folderName(origDir)) = True Then MsgBox "Greeeeeeat success" Else MsgBox "doh"
    If FileExists(batDir & "\" & "ILikeToLoveItMoveIt.bat") = True Then Kill batDir & "\" & "ILikeToLoveItMoveIt.bat"
End Sub

Function folderName(ByRef origDir As String) As String
    folderName = Right(origDir, Len(origDir) - InStrRev(origDir, "\", , vbTextCompare))
End Function

Sub MakeBat(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal contents As String)
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(FileName, True)
    a.WriteLine (contents)
    a.Close
End Sub

Function FireBat(ByRef FullName As String)
If dir(FullName, vbNormal) <> "" Then
    Call Shell(FullName, vbNormalFocus)
Else
    MsgBox "Bat not created"
End If
End Function

Function FileExists(ByVal FullPath As String) As Boolean
If dir(FullPath) <> "" Then
    FileExists = True
Else
    FileExists = False
End If
End Function

Function DirectoryExists(ByVal FullPath As String) As Boolean
If dir(FullPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
    DirectoryExists = True
Else
    DirectoryExists = False
End If
End Function
```